# Non-root users can't play audio with pipewire

Tags: rhel, audio, pipewire, alma-linux

I have an AlmaLinux 9 host which uses pipewire.  Logging in as root I can play audio files no problem.  But issuing the same command as any other user results in "host is down" error and no audio is played; eg:

```
pw-play -v /data/sounds/intercom-bong.wav
error: pw_context_connect() failed: Host is down
```

Also, if **as root** I run

```
sudo /usr/bin/pw-play -v /data/sounds/intercom-bong.wav
error: pw_context_connect() failed: Host is down
```

I get the exact same error.  I don't understand how that's possible since sudo means run it as root.

Ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how RHEL or Alma Linux does it, but on Debian, the audio devices created by `udev` are owned by `root`, in group `audio` with 660 permissions.

On my system, that looks like this:

```
$ ls -lF /dev/snd/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root      100 Jul 30 20:51 by-path/
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 13 Aug  1 21:25 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 12 Aug  1 21:25 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 18 Aug  1 21:25 controlC2
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 11 Aug  1 21:25 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 Aug  1 21:25 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 17 Aug  1 21:25 hwC2D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 Aug  6 19:26 pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 Aug  6 19:26 pcmC0D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  9 Aug  6 19:26 pcmC0D8p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 10 Aug  6 19:26 pcmC0D9p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 Aug  6 19:26 pcmC1D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 Aug  6 19:26 pcmC1D7p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 Aug  6 19:26 pcmC1D8p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 Aug  6 19:26 pcmC1D9p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 15 Aug  6 19:26 pcmC2D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 14 Aug 10 09:34 pcmC2D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 16 Aug  6 19:26 pcmC2D1p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 Jul 30 20:51 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 Aug  1 21:25 timer
```

You should:

1. examine your system to find out what group and permissions the /dev/snd device nodes are (probably `audio` and `660`, same as on debian),
2. make sure the users who are supposed to have access to audio devices are in that group.  (changes to group membership will require the use of `newgrp` or logging-out and logging-in again after adding a currently logged-in user to that group)
3. make sure that pipewire is actually running for the user. e.g. on one of my machines running pipewire:

```
$ ps u -C pipewire
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
username    6914  0.0  0.0 105708  8836 ?        S<sl Jul30   0:00 /usr/bin/pipewire
username    6915  0.0  0.0  94680  4948 ?        Ssl  Jul30   0:00 /usr/bin/pipewire -c filter-chain.conf
```

`pipewire` should be auto-started when the user logs in.  if it's not running, check the user's `~/.xsession-errors` file - if it started and then died, there may be a clue in there.

If it didn't start at all, check the session startup configuration for that user's window manager. If you're using xfce, that would be under `Settings Manager -> Settings and Startup -> Application Autostart`. If you're using gnome or some other WM, I have no idea - it's been 10+ years since I used gnome...but it'll probably be something similarly named.

Comment: my /dev/snd devices are identical, with same permissions.  Pipewire processes are run by sddm (and root since logged in as root I assume).  I have a service (running as root) that tries to run pw-play but gets the host is down message.  So as root it should already have permission (unless running as service changes that)