# Run one command as root within script

Tags: sudo, non-root-user

I have a script that I would like everyone (world) to be able to execute.  However, one line in the script requires root privilege to run properly.

How can I make this script work for everyone, without requiring anyone to enter root credentials?  If I preface the command with sudo then I assume every users will be prompted for root credentials.

```
#!/bin/bach
echo "works fine"
sudo rootonlycommand
echo "works fine"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo` allows for entries in `/etc/sudoers` to have a `NOPASSWD:` option.  And it also allows for `ALL` to be the source user.

So an entry such as

```
ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/id
```

Would allow anyone to run the `id` command without a password.

```
$ sudo -k -K
$ sudo /bin/id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$
```

Comment: +1.  Also worth noting: OP has to be extremely careful about which commands they allow to be run as root.  In particular, any programs that are capable of running other programs as they will also be run as root, for example editors such as `vi`, or text viewers such as `less` (which can run $EDITOR directly and any other program indirectly via $LESSOPEN).  BTW, some programs have options that disable "dangerous features" like this (e.g. `less` has a `-L` / `--no-less-open` option to cause it to ignore $LESSOPEN), and these can be used within `/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: In most cases, it's better not to allow sudo access to particular programs, instead allow access to a wrapper script that runs those programs with specific, pre-defined options and/or arguments.  e.g. if you need to allow a user to delete a particular file that they wouldn't normally have permission to delete, don't give them access to `sudo rm`, give them sudo access to a shell script that runs `rm /full/path/to/just/this/one/file`

Comment: Yes, I didn't go into the security concerns around what to grant `sudo` privileges to.  I was focusing on the question asked.   If the OP is concerned about that then I have a blog entry which explains how commands can be locked down (eg specific paramters) and the risks of wildcards and more ;-)  https://www.sweharris.org/post/2018-08-26-minimal-sudo/

Comment: yep, I just thought it was important to mention because not enough people know that they should be extremely cautious about the secondary or indirect consequences of allowing root access to a program.  It's very easy to accidentally give permission to run any program (and "any program" includes interactive shells, and scripting languages as well as obvious dangers like `rm`).

Comment: Good point.  I'm only running pw-play which should be safe.  (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/753669/non-root-users-cant-play-audio-with-pipewire).

Comment: using `sudo pw-play` to work around what's probably either a misconfiguration of pipewire OR a permissions or group membership problem sounds like a bad idea...brute-force Rube Goldberg-ing it into working rather than finding the source of the problem and fixing it.    I'll comment more on your other post.